# JavaScript giving element key to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm kinda lost in figuring out the logic for javascript.

Currently, I'm extracting every element and pushing them into an array.

I'm having a hard time when I want to access the object element.

This is the data in the text file:

```
1#1#test#Tombstone#8#Yes
2#3#test2#Tombstone3#81#Yes
```

When I access the first array `rowCells[0]` . It returns me

```
1
2
```

which is the first column itself.

I was hoping for it to return the first row. The intended functionality is as follows:

1- Push everything to an array

2- Giving element key like first column is `no,type,header,content,score`

3- Search all the row based on the element key such as `type=2`

4- Search based on the type and no, then show the content.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'content.txt',
  dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);


function successFunction(data) {
  var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
  var table = '<table>';
  for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
    var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split('#');
    //table += rowCells.toString();

    table += '<br>';
    var first_word = rowCells;
    table += first_word;


  } 
  $('body').append(table);
}
</script>
```

Comment: why does a table have a br tag?

Comment: @epascarello to test the line content , it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use split, reduce, split, and join to build the table.

```js
var str = `1#1#test#Tombstone#8#Yes
2#3#test2#Tombstone3#81#Yes`

var rows = str.split(/\n/g).reduce( function (str, row) {
  return str + "<tr><td>" + row.split(/#/g).join("</td><td>")  + "</td></tr>";
}, "")

var table = "<table><tbody>" + rows + "</tbody></table>"
$("#out").append(table)
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: really appreciate for your answer, but let's say if i just want to show specific elements , like type = 3 . So ill need to push the elements to a key for me to match the criteria then only do it into a table.

Comment: so add an if statement when you generate it. `var cells = row.split(/#/g); if (cells[0]=="2"){} else {}`